# roslaunch gives error which says ' Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher '

Tags: tensorflow, keras, ros, reinforcement-learning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quTnq.png)

I've got these versions installed on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
/rosdistro: kinetic
/rosversion: 1.12.15
tensorboard                   2.3.0,
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.7.0,
tensorflow                    2.3.0,
tensorflow-estimator          2.3.0,
tensorflow-gpu                2.3.0,
Keras                         2.4.3,
Keras-Applications            1.0.8,
Keras-Preprocessing           1.1.2,
h5py                          2.10.0.
```

On the other tab roscore is runing and before launching I've made source/home/bellatrix/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash. Meanwhile I'm getting this error which says I didn't installed TensorFlow. I've already tried changing keras.models to keras.py in the code but it seem rospack don't see Keras or TensorFlow.

Comment: Hi, seems there's an issue here, i wonder that's might help https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/1613